# Can't figure out how to prevent Samsung drivers to fail with error code 10

Tags: samsung, usb-drivers

I tried to install Samsung drivers (to be able to connect my Galaxy J5 J500FN) on windows 7 or windows 10 in virtualbox (Linux host).

None of my attempts works, I always have an error 'code 10': 'device cannot start.'

Virtualbox recognize the USB device, but not windows.

I took 2 days on duckduckgo and such, try many ways, but nothing work !

Any clue ?

Comment: Where did you download the drivers?

Comment: Downloaded from Samsung yesterday.

Tried from xda too and installed Media Transfer Protocol Porting Kit from Official Microsoft, also trying installing kies